# Maven package:mvn package

Tags: java, maven, package

I have a maven project, but the father and son structure, I would like to perform mvn package in the parent structure at the same time want to specify the sub-project `pom.xml` file profile an id

Comment: Why would you like to have a profile for that? Do you know about `mvn -pl ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the `sub-project` module in your `parent` pom file profile as below:

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>all-deps</id>
      <modules>
         <module>sub-project</module>
       </modules>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now you can use following maven commands to include the `sub-project` from `parent`

```
mvn package --activate-profiles all-deps
```